# A new category $C^*$ from a given category $C$

Tags: category-theory, terminology

For a given category $C$ define the category $C^*$ as follows: the objects of $C^*$ are those of $C$; for given objects $u,v$, the $C^*$-morphisms $u\to v$ are all finite sequences $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ of morphisms $a_i\in Mor(C)$ such that $a_1:u\to x$ and $a_n:y\to v$ where $x$ and $y$ are arbitrary objects (no other restrictions). The composition of two composable morphisms is $$(a_1,\dots,a_m)(b_1,\dots,b_n)=(a_1,\dots,a_mb_1,\dots,b_n)$$ (where $a_mb_1$ are composed in $C$). My question: is there an established name for the category $C^*$?

Update:

1) Motivation: the construction $C\mapsto C^*$ appears as a **tool of proof** in my research and I wanted to know if, where and for which purpose this construction appears in literature, in order to insert some references. Intuitively I would say this is somehow the *free category generated by $C \cup (C\times C)$ modulo the relations which hold in $C$.*

2) Intuitive background: I have algebraic terms of a certain type which can be interpreted as instructions what to do in a certain category $C$. There are two sorts of instructions:

a) type $w$: they tell me I should compose certain morphisms of $C$  the result of which  is the morphism $a_1$, say, and thereby I run through the underlying graph $\Gamma$ of $C$

b) type $w^{\mathfrak m}$: they say I should jump elsewhere in the graph $\Gamma$

The application of such instructions alternatingly ends up with a tuple $(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)$ as in the question. The category $C^*$ seems to model exactly this behaviour. For technical reasons, I allow in type b) "empty jumps", that is, even if two consecutive morphisms $a_i$ and $a_{i+1}$ are composable in $C$ I would like to distinguish between $\dots a_i,a_{i+1}\dots$ and $\dots a_ia_{i+1}\dots$.

Comment: Does the composition have $n+m-1$ terms?

Comment: @Dog_69 Yes, the adjacent morphisms $a_m$ and $b_1$ are composed in $C$, so $a_mb_1$ is one entry of the sequence.

Comment: And I suppose that two morphisms if $m=n$ and they agree in each component, isn't it?

Comment: Do you have a particular reason to think that this category may have an established name? The definition looks a bit arbitrary to me...

Comment: @Dog_69 No, for every $n$ there can be many tuples of length $n$ (I'm not sure if I understood the question correctly).

Comment: @Arnaud D. I have inserted motivation and intuitive background. I'm more interested whether the construction appears elsewhere than in a name (I wanted a name to do a search).

Comment: @user59363 I'm sorry, I didn't write the question completely. I meant two morphisms are the same if $m=n$ and they agree in each component.

Comment: @Dog_69 Yes, exactly.

Answer (score -1):

It looks to me like the two categories are exactly same! The objects are the same so take 2 arbitrary objects A and B, then you can see that the Hom(A,B) in C and C* are in bijection.

Comment: This is not the case. For example, if $C$ is finite, $C^*$ will be infinite (if $C$ has at least two different morphisms).

Comment: I don't see this. Among the morphisms in $C^*$ from $A$ to $B$, you have all the morphisms in $C$ from $A$ to $B$ (regarded as sequences of length 1), and you also have sequence of greater length. Note that a directed path n $C$ from $A$ to $B$ is a morphism in $C^*$ and has not been identified with the composite of its members. Furthermore, the terms $a_i$ in a $C^*$-morphism needn't even line up to form a path in $C$.

Comment: Yes my answer is wrong, I will fix it when I can. The empty sequence of morphisms should be admitted too, as identity, correct?

Comment: @magma No, the empty sequence is not admitted.

Comment: So what sequence is the identity on A?

Comment: @magma The identity at an object $A$ is the sequence $(1_A)$, with $1_A$ the identity morphism at $A$ in $C$; but there is no "empty sequence" which would be somehow a  "global identity" (categories usually do not have such).

Comment: oh I see, I did not understand the category morphisms correctly.   what is the name of this category?